# C++ macros: order of precedence difference?

Tags: c++, macros

I have this simple code that converts between degrees Farehnheit and degrees Celcius. I defined some macros to do it, but I'm getting some weird results when I use it. I use this method when `absoluteTemp` = 373.15 (the boiling point of water in kelvin).

```
#define kelvinToCelc(k) k - 273.15
#define celcToFahren(c) (9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32

double x = kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp);              // 100
double y = celcToFahren(x);                          // 212
double z = celcToFahren(kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp)); // 430.52???
return celcToFaren(kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp));
```

Comment: These would be much better as functions. And http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e592437849fd9ca

Comment: use inline function instead of macro to save some troubles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After expanding macro in

```
double z = celcToFahren(kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp));
```

It becomes

```
double z = (9.0 / 5.0) * absoluteTemp - 273.15 + 32
```

You need to add parentheses to the macros

```
#define kelvinToCelc(k) (k - 273.15)
#define celcToFahren(c) ((9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32)
```

Comment: And the second. Just imagine if `c` is `x + y`.

Comment: You probably should add paranthesis to all the macros to avoid precedence screwing up your math.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it offered a good explanation and solution

Comment: @doctordoder - not to repeat my answer but, you should also put parens around the `k` and `c` if you must use macros, but really you should use inline functions and avoid the whole mess

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Is there anything you want to add to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1137654/2770572) on another thread about inline functions vs macros? The concept is new to me, and I'd appreciate some direction. It seems simple to me, in the same place I'd put define, just make a simple function there instead with `inline` in front of it.

Comment: @doctordoder take a look at my answer, I editted to show you what the transformation will look like for your macros

Answer (score 2):

The old rule was : Use more parenthesis in macros around everything:

```
#define kelvinToCelc(k) ((k) - 273.15)
#define celcToFahren(c) ((9.0 / 5.0) * (c) + 32)
```

Notice parens around the whole macro and all macro arguments

The new rule is : **Use inline functions** They have typechecking, evaluate arguments only once, and because they don't need so many parenthesis *

Note: * *Some exceptions may apply, this is not one of them*

This is what that looks like as inline functions

```
inline double kelvinToCelc(double k)
{
    return k - 273.15;
}

inline double kelvinToCelc(double c)
{
    return (9.0 / 5.0) * c + 32;
}
```

Notice that you have to put `inline` and the return type before the name, add types to all arguments, and add a `;` at the end

Notice how you can use newlines to make it easier to read, and also so you can step into it in the debugger

Comment: Note: the functions may also be `constexpr` in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are simple - Just a text replacement

i.e.

```
 double z = celcToFahren(kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp));
```

becomes

```
 double z = (9.0 / 5.0) * kelvinToCelc(absoluteTemp) + 32
```

Then becomes

```
 double z = (9.0 / 5.0) * absoluteTemp - 273.15  + 32
```

Now just do the maths

i.e.

```
double z = (9.0 / 5.0) * 373.15 - 273.15  + 32;
```

Comment: You say macros are simple. I sentence you to an hour of staring at the Boost.Preprocessor implementation (or quite a few other libraries, even with those amazing utilities).

Comment: @chris - I find them simple - Just use a pencil and a rubber

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use macros, make your life easier with parenthesis

```
#define kelvinToCelc(k) (k) - 273.15
#define celcToFahren(c) (9.0 / 5.0) * (c) + 32
```

This helps prevent the unexpected results you are seeing.  The reasons have already been pointed out in other posts

Answer (score 0):

For macros, it just relies on textual substitution. So it is equivalent to:

```
double z = (9.0 / 5.0) * absoluteTemp - 273.15 + 32;
```

That's why you got wrong result.

**Edit:**

1. Try to ***use (inline) functions instead*** even you can make it work by adding more parenthesis: (see #2)

   ```
   #define celcToFahren(c) ((9.0 / 5.0) * (c) + 32)
   ```
2. Macros are also ***error-prone*** because they rely on textual substitution and do not perform type-checking. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c) for more info.

Comment: Edit 1 isn't a very good solution. `celcToFahren(x) * 5` for example would result in unwanted behaviour again (the `32` would be multiplied by `5`).

Comment: @user2176127 Fixed by adding MORE parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: It seems Lisp is just C's arithmetic macro idioms turned into a language.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing i should add to the other answers, try running just the preprocessor and look at the output ie:
    g++ -E -P main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The answer 431.52 is correct. It expanded like this

```
(9.0/5.0) * 373.15 - 272.15 + 32
```

In mathematics [* and /] take precedence over [+ and -]. So the equation expanded like

```
((9.0/5.0) * 373.15) - 272.15 + 32
(671.67) - 272.15 + 32
399.52 + 32
431.52
```

[* and /] have same precedence so there order doesn't matter and similarly [+ and -] have same precedence so their execution order doesn't matter.