# Why is the output 16? (C pogramming)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define sqr(x) x*x

int main()    
{    
    int a = 16/sqr(4);

    printf("%d", a);    
}
```

if I am not wrong the output should be 1
as ,a = 16/sqr(4) gives 16/16 => 1

but the output is 16

this is happening only when I take division operator(/) ,I am getting correct output when using other operators

may I know the reason? .. and thank you

Comment: Hint: operator precedence.

Comment: ```16/sqr(4)```, after preprocessor will be ```16/16*16```, so the result of course ```16```

Comment: Expand it out. It will be `16 / 4 * 4`

Comment: `#define sqr(x) x*x` better as `#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ macros: order of precedence difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153061/c-macros-order-of-precedence-difference)

Comment: This article presents some  rules to write macros in a secured and robust way: http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/c_preprocessor.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`16 / 4 * 4` is `(16 / 4) * 4` = `16`

Moral: always take care with macros. In your case you should enclose in parenthesis:

```
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
```

There are still problems with this macro as it evaluates the argument twice.

For instance:

```
int read_int();

int a = 16 / sqr(read_int());
```

Will unexpectedly evaluate `read_int()` twice as it expands to:

```
int a = 16 / ((read_int() * (read_int());
```

---

The advice would be to use functions for this. Make it inline to give the compiler better chances to optimize it.

Comment: Always assume your macros will be abused and gird them accordingly :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 16/sqr(4);
```

Expanded the above expression gives:

```
a = 16 / 4 * 4
```

Which is 16 based on normal mathematical order of operations.

That's why macros should always be enclosed in parentheses:

```
#define sqr(x) ((x) * (x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a **function definiton**? If yes, then i don't think it should be on a `#define`. Instead, make a function `sqr(x)`. Here's how:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sqr(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 16/sqr(4);

    printf("%d", a);
}
```

And you'll get the result 1.

Edit: but anyway, you've already get the solution with macros. This is just another way to do what you want.