# convert a one line function to a macro in c

Tags: c, macros

I have a function which I want to convert to a macro without violating type safety

```
#define UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1 (uintptr_t) (UINTPTR_MAX ^ 1)
struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    tbb::atomic<struct node*> lChild;    //format <address,flagBit>
    tbb::atomic<struct node*> rChild;    //format <address,flagBit>
};

struct node* getAddress(struct node* p)
{
    return (struct node*)((uintptr_t) p & UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1);
}

main()
{
    nodeAddr = getAddress(node);
    lNodeAddr = getAddress(node->lChild);
}
```

I try to replace `getAddress()` function with this macro. I know this macro definition is wrong.

```
#define getAddress(p) ((struct node*) (uintptr_t) p & UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1)
```

I read this post
[Macro vs Function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c)
But still couldn't figure how to do it for this case

Comment: The function is surely better than the macro. And your main is quite funky.

Comment: Why do think the function is better than a macro. The main is more complicated. I just put the relevant code here :)

Comment: Macros are usually worse. Why do you prefer them?

Comment: Your macro doesn't match your `return` statement: parentheses are missing.

Comment: @David: I thought using macros would get rid of the function call overhead

Comment: Is that overhead significant? What does your profiling tell you of te performance difference?

Comment: Profiling did not show any considerable difference. I wanted to try various options as the function `getAddress()` is one of the hotspots in my code.

Comment: another basic question. `#define UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1 (uintptr_t) (UINTPTR_MAX ^ 1)` When this macro gets unrolled in the source code at compilation time, will it have the value of `(UINTPTR_MAX ^ 1)` or will this value get computed at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost equivalent, except that the macro is more permissive than the function when type-checking its argument:

```
#define getAddress(p) ((struct node*) ((uintptr_t) (struct node*)(p) & UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1))
```

Some C compilers accept `static inline`, that's not a macro, but it's equivalent to the original function, and will get inlined most of the time in practice:

```
static inline struct node* getAddress(struct node* p) {
  return (struct node*)((uintptr_t) p & UINTPTR_MAX_XOR_WITH_1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. It worked perfect. I'm using `gcc` with `-O3` flag enabled. Since this is a one line function I expected it to get inlined during compilation

Comment: What does the _double_ cast to `p` do?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: I think you are right. `(uintptr_t) (p)` would be fine. Since `p` is of type `struct node*`, it it redundant to typecast it again

Comment: @arunmoezhi: In this case it's indeed redundant, but in general it's useful to start with typecasting the macro argument, to make sure that it is of the type we expect.

Comment: @pts: Thanks. I understand. You did that as a sanity check.