# Is getchar defined as macro?

Tags: c, function, macros, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

I read in K&R at page 90 that getchar is often defined as macro.

So, why does this code actually work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#undef getchar

int main()
{
    char c;
    c= getchar();
    printf("%c\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, clearly it's not.

Comment: Many standard library functions are **also** defined as macros.

Comment: Because getchar is a libc function

Comment: Try to step into `getchar` with a debugger. You might be able to get the answer from that (even if the debugger takes you into disassembled code).

Comment: @goodvibration even if `getchar` is defined as a function it might get inlined. So stepping through a debugger is not telling him anything.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. It is a Function like macro.

**C99 7.1.4(P1):**

> **Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a
>   function-like macro deﬁned in the header**,so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one
>   of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by
>   such a macro.

Comment: and the question is *still* a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> So, why does this code actually work?

Because `getchar()` is not just a macro, but a function-like macro.

Read more in [How are getchar() and putchar() Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760438/how-are-getchar-and-putchar-macros)

Answer (score 1):

Macros can be cleverly disguised as functions (in C they are called *function-like macros*), particularly if your preprocessor supports *expression statements*.

So long as `getchar()` does what the C standard mandates what it ought to do, it could be (i) a macro, (ii) a function, or even (iii) hardcoded into the compiler itself.

These days, it's unlikely that `getchar()` is implemented as a macro.

Reference: [Function-like Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html).

Comment: From openbsd git hub repo's stdio.h file : #define getchar() getc(stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the C standard defines `getchar()` as a function. See `C11`, chapter 7.21.7.6, *The `getchar` function*. It is prototyped in `<stdio.h>` header file.

Any implementation, if chose to define this as a MACRO, then it's limited to that implementation only. Point to note, it's not non-conformance. From chapter §7.1.4 (*emphasis mine*)

> Any function
>   declared in a header **may be additionally implemented** as a function-like macro defined in
>   the header,

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` is not necessarily a macro. I don't know why K&R claim that but it's possible that in earlier days it was *de facto*.